# How to get the metdata of the Google Cloud Storage Bucket using Google Cloud Storage Client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to create the function in `python` the that helps to enumerate the meta-data using the Google Cloud Storage Client Library Functions

I already created the function that list the bucket I just wanna to display the metadata of the buckets as shown here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets#resource

```
     for bucket in self.client.list_buckets():
         print(bucket)
#  this list the all the buckets
```

I want something like this

```
  def meta(self):
      bucket_name="sample"
    //It should print the metadata of the bucket not the metadata of object inside the bucket
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a "protected" member of `google.cloud.storage.Client` that is a map of bucket properties, closely matching the API representation document you're looking for. It's subject to change since it is not in the exposed API, but you can get a clear idea what is available right now. Here's a snippet:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pprint
from typing import Dict

from google.cloud import storage

BUCKET_NAME = "your-bucket-here"

def get_bucket_metadata(bucket_name: str, gcs: storage.Client) -> Dict[str, str]:
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    return bucket._properties

def main():
    gcs = storage.Client()
    metadata = get_bucket_metadata(BUCKET_NAME, gcs)
    pprint(metadata)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I found this by running `print(dir(bucket))` and examining the available methods and properties. You may find others that interest you that way.

Here's an example of the output:

```
{'etag': 'CAE=',
 'iamConfiguration': {'bucketPolicyOnly': {'enabled': False}},
 'id': 'your-bucket-here',
 'kind': 'storage#bucket',
 'location': 'US-WEST1',
 'metageneration': '1',
 'name': 'your-bucket-here',
 'projectNumber': '264682420247',
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/your-bucket-here',
 'storageClass': 'REGIONAL',
 'timeCreated': '2019-02-20T21:53:30.130Z',
 'updated': '2019-02-20T21:53:30.130Z'}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of methods that can be called on the class `google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket` [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html).

For example:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

print(bucket.name)
print(bucket.time_created)
print(bucket.project_number)
print(bucket.cors)

...
```